# How to create 3D model from live face in iOS like in Lenskart,snapchat?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, arkit, google-mlkit

I am working on swift native project and I tried Google MLKit for face detection using below pod file.

***pod 'GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection'***

I can identify the face detection and I can draw the line. But I want to add objects like specs, beard etc... Is it possible to add these object in Google ML kit? or do I need to choose Apple ARKit?

I followed this documentation for creating demo app:
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/ios

Comment: Using Google ML Kit, you will need to add specs, beard, etc yourself (possibly based on the positions of the facial landmarks detected by ML Kit).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try to add objects.